# What regular expression could apply to obtain the Data Frame of the following response

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

Good morning I have a question or concern, I am working with python to make ssh connections to some computers and get an answer, the question is that there is an answer that I cannot obtain in the best way in a dataframe for treatment.

I have the following answer:

```
print(data)

Interface                     PHY     Protocol Description                     
GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0
GE1/2/8                       up      up       Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1     
GE1/2/9                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *2/1/6 (Servicio 608 1Gbps) IP7VAL01 Gi4/0/1
```

When I apply the following line of code to obtain the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
print(df)
                                                              Interface  \
GE1/2/7 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5   (Servicio     1711.0   
GE1/2/8 up up Conexion a IP7MCY01          Gi1/0/1 NaN              NaN   
GE1/2/9 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6   (Servicio      608.0   

                                                                 PHY  \
GE1/2/7 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5   (Servicio  1Gbps)   
GE1/2/8 up up Conexion a IP7MCY01          Gi1/0/1 NaN           NaN   
GE1/2/9 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6   (Servicio  1Gbps)   

                                                              Protocol  \
GE1/2/7 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5   (Servicio  IP7BTO01   
GE1/2/8 up up Conexion a IP7MCY01          Gi1/0/1 NaN             NaN   
GE1/2/9 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6   (Servicio  IP7VAL01   

                                                             Description  
GE1/2/7 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 1/1/5   (Servicio     Gi7/0/0  
GE1/2/8 up up Conexion a IP7MCY01          Gi1/0/1 NaN               NaN  
GE1/2/9 up up Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 2/1/6   (Servicio     Gi4/0/1
```

I am trying to assemble the separator (sep) with regular expressions, but the REGEX issue is still difficult for me to understand, as you can see by using the expression \ s + as a separator, but in my last column I don't get what I want.

**UPDATE**:Apart from the solution provided by the friend @Elegant Odoo, I got another one that might be easier for a lot and basically based on treating the data before converting it into a dataframe, so what I did was pass my string to the list, transform the space found in the strings of the description column in underscores (_), then take it to string again, so now you can use the '\ s +' separator in my dataframe.

```
data=list(data)                  # Transformo mi data(de tipo string) en una lista para su manipulacion
# print(data)
count1=(len(data))               # Cuento el total de elemento que tiene mi lista
print(data[47])                  # Variable que me desmuestra que desde exite 47 caracteres desde el inicio de mi cadena hasta el incio de la ultima "columna"
while i < count1:              
    if z >= 47 and data[ind] !='\n' :             
        if data[ind]==' ':  
            data[ind]='_'
    elif data[ind]=='\n':       
        z=-1      
    i+=1
    ind+=1                    
    z+=1
#   print(z)
data=''.join(data)      
# print(data)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep='\s+') 
df=df.rename(columns = {'Description_____________________':'Description'})      
print(df)
```

And my definitive dataframe:

```
       Interface    PHY Protocol  \
0      EthTrunk4  *down     down   
1      EthTrunk8     up       up   
2   GE7/1/5(10G)  *down     down   
3   GE7/1/6(10G)     up       up   
4   GE7/1/7(10G)     up       up   
5   GE7/1/9(10G)     up       up   
6  GE16/1/5(10G)  *down     down   
7  GE16/1/7(10G)     up       up   

                                         Description  
0           LAGPED76MCY01_2/43/4PNEMCY01_7/1/516/1/5  
1  LAGPNE5MCY01_GE7/1/7GE16/1/7PED77MCY03_Te3/1/3...  
2  Conexion_a_PED76MCY01_2/43/4PNEMCY01_7/1/516/1...  
3                   Conexion_a_PED76MCY01_Te0/8/0/0_  
4  Conexion_a_LAGPNE5MCY01_GE7/1/9PED77MCY03_Te3/...  
5  Conexion_a_YMTSOMCY7750SR1201_3/2/1_(Servicio_...  
6  Conexion_a_PED76MCY01_2/43/4PNEMCY01_7/1/516/1...  
7  Conexion_a_LAGPNE5MCY01_GE7/1/9PED77MCY03_Te8/...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `sep='\s'`, second line mean that it contains **12 columns** ?:

```
# take a look at this
print(len(re.split('\s+', "GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0")))
```

If if all your columns are separated by more than one space just fix the case in your header
and use `sep=(\s\s+)`:

```
    # add antoher space 
    data = data.replace('Protocol Description', 'Protocol  Description')
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+')
    print(df)
```

output:

```
   Interface PHY Protocol                                        Description
0   GE1/2/7  up       up  Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *1/1/5 (Servicio ...
1   GE1/2/8  up       up                        Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1
2   GE1/2/9  up       up  Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *2/1/6 (Servicio ...
```

If that didn't work you need to fix your data to be a valid sperated csv format, an example
for you demo data:

```
    # here first line start with \n when spliting \n first element of lise is an empty string.
    data = """
    Interface                     PHY     Protocol Description                     
    GE1/2/7                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *1/1/5 (Servicio 1711 1Gbps) IP7BTO01 Gi7/0/0
    GE1/2/8                       up      up       Conexion a IP7MCY01 Gi1/0/1     
    GE1/2/9                       up      up       Conexion a YMTSOMCY7750SR702 *2/1/6 (Servicio 608 1Gbps) IP7VAL01 Gi4/0/1
    """

    data_copy = ''
    pattern = '\s\s+'  # all columns except the header are separated by more than one space
    for index, line in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
        if not line: continue  # skip dummy lines
        # here i'm just checking the first line because it contains a special case
        # Protocol Description  are separated by one space only this why i'm writing
        # all this code to explain the idea
        if all(x in line for x in ['Interface', 'PHY', 'Protocol', 'Description']):
            line = re.sub('\s+', ',', line)
        else:
            # from your data lucky you column are separated by more than one space
            line = re.sub('\s\s+', ',', line)
        # some line ends with a sequence of spaces this lines will contains ',' at the end
        if line.endswith(','):
            line = line[:-1]
        # skip line that don't respect separation by more than one space
        if line.count(',') != 3:
            print("line number %s contains more than 4 columns")
            continue
        data_copy += line + '\n'

    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_copy), sep=',')
    print(df['Interface'])
```

out put:

```py
    0    GE1/2/7
    1    GE1/2/8
    2    GE1/2/9
    Name: Interface, dtype: object
```

Comment: I got another solution, but I will try this one that looks very optimized. Thank you